# Parsing RDFa in html/xhtml?

Tags: html, xml, perl, parsing, rdfa

Using RDF::RDFa::Parser module in perl to parse rdf data out of website.
On website with with !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> it works, but on sites using xhtml !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> no output...

test website -> http://www.filmstarts.de/kritiken/186918.html

```
use RDF::RDFa::Parser;

my $url     = 'http://www.filmstarts.de/kritiken/186918.html';
my $options = RDF::RDFa::Parser::Config->tagsoup;
my $rdfa    = RDF::RDFa::Parser->new_from_url($url, $options);

print $rdfa->opengraph('image');
print $rdfa->opengraph('description');
```

Answer (score 5):

(I'm the author of RDF::RDFa::Parser.)

It looks like the HTML parser used by the RDFa parser is failing on that page. (I'm also the maintainer of the HTML parser in question, so I can't shift the blame onto anyone else!) Thus, by the time the RDFa parsing starts, all it sees is an empty DOM tree.

The page is [quite hideously invalid XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.filmstarts.de/kritiken/186918.html) yet still I would have expected the HTML parser to do a reasonable job. I've [filed a bug report for you](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=91645).

In the mean time, a workaround might be to build the XML::LibXML DOM tree *outside of* RDF::RDFa::Parser (perhaps using libxml's built-in HTML parser?). You could pass that tree directly to the RDFa parser:

```
use RDF::RDFa::Parser;
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

my $url     = 'http://www.filmstarts.de/kritiken/186918.html';
my $xhtml   = get($url);
my $dom     = somehow_build_a_dom_tree($xhtml);  # hand-waving!!
my $options = RDF::RDFa::Parser::Config->tagsoup;
my $rdfa    = RDF::RDFa::Parser->new($dom, $url, $options);

print $rdfa->opengraph('image');
print $rdfa->opengraph('description');
```

I hope that helps!

**Update:** here's a possible implementation of `somehow_build_a_dom_tree`...

```
sub somehow_build_a_dom_tree {
    my $p = XML::LibXML->new;
    $p->recover_silently(1);
    $p->load_html( string => @_ );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, how should i build a dom tree? Here is a working link with html 4.01 -> http://www.videoworld.de/DVD~179029~vw~30615/DVD-Verleih-Elysium.html thats works perfect...